# ggforest (survminer) only selected covariates

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, r-forestplot

I would like to create a forest plot after Cox survival models. However, I would liketo display only some of the covariates in the graph? Does someone know if it is possible? Maybe using ggforest2?
Thanks

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere,
               data = colon )
ggforest(model)

colon <- within(colon, {
  sex <- factor(sex, labels = c("female", "male"))
  differ <- factor(differ, labels = c("well", "moderate", "poor"))
  extent <- factor(extent, labels = c("submuc.", "muscle", "serosa", "contig."))
})
bigmodel <-
  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere + differ + extent + node4,
        data = colon )
ggforest(bigmodel)
```

Answer (score 2):

The current version of `ggforest` on my machine does not allow me to select variables to be presented in the plot. However, another package `forestmodel::forest_model` has `covariates =` which is supposed to allow users to select variables. However, the current version of `forestmodel` may not perform this correctly, as you can see from the following graph:

```
colon <- within(colon, {
  sex <- factor(sex, labels = c("female", "male"))
  differ <- factor(differ, labels = c("well", "moderate", "poor"))
  extent <- factor(extent, labels = c("submuc.", "muscle", "serosa", "contig."))
})
bigmodel <-
  coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere + differ + extent + node4,
        data = colon )
forest_model(bigmodel, covariates = c("sex", "rx"))
```

[image]

It might be something the original contributor could fix. At some stage, I was able to generate something like this with some minor modification of previous version of the function. However, after I reinstalled the updated package, it no longer works.

[image]

**EDIT**

Another approach would be flexible. It takes two steps. First, collect model information (I use `broom::tidy` here but you can use other methods. Second, use `forestplot::forest_plot`to produce the graph. Again, you can also use other Meta analysis package for this.
Let's continue with the above `bigmodel`

```
library(forestplot)
library(tidyverse)
# Save model information
df <- broom::tidy(bigmodel,  exponentiate = TRUE)
# pick up the first 4 values 
df1 <- df[1:4, ] %>% 
  transmute( 
    HR = round(estimate, 2), 
    low = conf.low, 
    high = conf.high)

row_names <- cbind(c("Name", "Sex", "Lev", "Lev + 5FU", "adhere"),
                   c("HR", df1$HR))
df1 <- rbind(rep(NA, 4), df1)
forestplot(labeltext = row_names,
           df1[,c("HR", "low", "high")],
           is.summary=c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
           zero      = 1,
           xlog      = TRUE)
```

This produces the following graph. It may take a little bit more learning to generate a satisfactory graph, but you are in control, relatively.
[image]